# Game Theory for Tic-Tac-Toe on a Torus

Tags: game-theory, tic-tac-toe

I recently discovered playing tic-tac-toe on a torus; I have not been able to achieve a draw. Is there a proof using game theory that says that tic-tac-toe on torus cannot end in draw?

Comment: I don't think this has anything to do with game theory.  Instead, it is simple geometrical constraints.

Comment: If it's only 3x3 you should be able to just check the entire game tree

Comment: It's very quick to check. Every starting square is the "center" square! There are only two possible responses for the second player, and each one leads quickly to a forced win. One can even make the case-checking quicker by noticing that the torus variant is just looking for lines in $\Bbb F_3^2$, and linear transformations preserve that structure—so there's really only one possible first-move for the second player up to symmetry.

Comment: Thank you @GregMartin. It is quite simple.

Comment: @GregMartin Should probably convert that to an answer :)

Comment: https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/576864/prove-that-a-game-of-tic-tac-toe-played-on-the-torus-can-never-end-in-a-draw-g more mathematical proof.

Comment: It would help if you would visualize how this game works.

Comment: Moreover, you should clarify whether you mean a legal game ending in a draw, or whether perfect play will end in a draw. This could be the same after all here, but nevertheless...